# How to get imported functions to set state of functional component?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-functional-component

I have a react class component with rather lengthy onSubmit function that I have put into another file in order to keep the code a bit tidier.

I tried to convert the class component to a functional one, replacing all of my state and setState functions with useState but now my useState state updaters are returning undefined inside the imported function. Am I able to update state using an imported function with a functional component? The function worked fine when it was imported into a class component and my state updater was setState();

```
//Imported function in utils.js

export const loginUser = async function (email, password) {
    try {
        const login = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login', {
            email,
            password
        });
        const options = {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${login.data.token}`
            }
        };
        const getUser = await axios.get(
            'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/me',
            options
        );
        const user = getUser.data.data;
        setAuthenticated(true);
        setUser(getUser.data.data);
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');

        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

// Functional component with imported function

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Login } from './Login';


const { loginUser } = require('../utils/utils');

export const Splash = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');


    const _handleEmail = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value);
    };

    const _handlePass = (e) => {
        setPassword(e.target.value);
    };

    const _handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginUser(email, password);
        if (user) {
            console.log(user);
            this.props.onHandleUser(user);
        }
    };

return (
        <div className='splashStyle'>
            {!authenticated && (
                <Login
                    handleEmail={_handleEmail}
                    handlePass={_handlePass}
                    handleSubmit={_handleSubmit}
                    isAuthenticated={authenticated}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};d
```

EDIT: My issue that setAuthenticated, setUser, setEmail, and setPassword are coming undefined in utils.js

Thanks!

Comment: Normally in the app, after the user logins, they expect to redirect to another page. Why is there no redirection function in your case? And why do you need to reinitialized email and password after submitting the form. After submitting the form, there is no purpose of the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of achieving that would be passing all the set methods as a paramters to `loginUser` function.

But a better way of doing this will be like:

create two separate files

1 for login api call like :

login.js

```
function login(email, password){
    const login = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/login', {
        email,
        password
    });
    return login.data;
}
```

another for getting data

getProfile.js

```
function getProfile(token){
    const options = {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    };
    const getUser = await axios.get(
        'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/auth/me',
        options
    );
    return getUser.data;
}
```

Now do you setting state stuff in actuall component submit call function like

```
const _handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const token = await login(email, password);
    const user = await getProfile(token);
    if (user) {
        console.log(user);
        props.onHandleUser(user);
        setAuthenticated(true);
        setUser(getUser.data.data);
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');

        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    }
};
```

Comment: this.props.onHandleUser is problematic because in the functional component you need to use only props instead of this.props, Because the this is for class components

Comment: @TalOrlanczyk yes you"re right, actually I have just copied those lines from the questions. Now I've updated my answer, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: forget to tell you to add an if statement to the const user because he is relying on the token
 I say that because the function name seems like you need the token and then you get the profile info
also if he got the token it's mean the user exist I think so you only need to check for the token (this i am not sure about so I will be happy if you correct me)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the **setAuthenticated** function to the **loginUser** function before calling it in that.

Comment: You right but he will still have a problem in the future due the use of this keyword and try to access props without enter props in the ()

Answer (score 0):

return an onSubmiHandler function from your login user hook.

```
const doLogin = (email , password) => {

  /// your code here

}

return {doLogin}
```

then use the doLogin function inside your main component

```
  //inside functional component

  const {doLogin} = loginUser();

  
  onSubmit = () => doLogin(email, password)
```

for more you can see how to use custom hooks from here

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Answer (score 0):

To start **loginUser** can't know about the **setState** you insert there try to pass it as arguments and it will fix it

another problem I see is that you use the **this** keyword and in the functional component you use the just **props**.

and just for you to know don't pass null as the initial value pass an empty string, number, etc..
**Update**

this is how you also pass a setState as argument

```
 loginUser((e)=>setEmail(e))
```

Comment: You're saying pass setAuthenticated, setEmail, etc... as arguments? How would I do that? Yeah.. this is very much a work in progress. I probably did not make my code completely right before I posted. Sorry!

Comment: first it's fine everyone ask it's doesn't matter if the code is bad or good,
and I will edit my post